# Undetermined Coefficients: $2y'' + 3y' + y = t^2 + 3\sin(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having trouble coming up with the "guess" for this differential equation.

I know for the "$t^{2}$" the guess would be $At^2 + Bt + C$

And for the "$3\sin(t)$" the guess would be $A\cos(t) + B\sin(t)$

But I do not know how to combine the guesses.

Comment: Note that the ODE is linear, which satisfies the superposition principle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add them: $y_p = A t^2 + Bt + C + D \cos t + E \sin t$

Answer (score 0):

Given that the second order non-homogeneous linear differential equation is

$$2\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+3\frac{dy}{dy}+y=t^2+3\sin(t)$$

The non-homogeneous term is $t^2+3\sin(t)$

The homogeneous differential equation is

$$2\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+3\frac{dy}{dy}+y=0$$

Finding the complementary solution, we need auxiliary equation

$$y=e^{mt}$$

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=me^{mt}$$

$$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}=m^2e^{mt}$$

$$2m^2+3m+1=0, e^{mt}\neq0$$

Factorization

$$(2m+1)(m+1)=0$$

$$m=-\frac{1}{2},m=-1$$

The complementary solution is $y_c=c_1e^{\frac{-t}{2}}+c_2e^{-t}$

Undetermined coefficients sets of the non-homogeneous differential equation

$$S_1={{t^2,t,1}}$$

$$S_2={\sin t ,\cos t }$$

Do these sets repeat themselves? No.
Are these sets inside the complementary function? No.

The particular solution can be written as

$$y_p=At^2+Bt+C+D\sin t +E\cos t$$

$$y_p'=2At+B+ D\cos t-E\sin t$$

$$y_p''=2A- D\sin t- E\cos t$$

Plugging them into the differential equation we have

$$2(2A- D\sin t- E\cos t)+3(2At+B+ D\cos t-E\sin t)+(At^2+Bt+C+D\sin t +E\cos t)=t^2+3\sin(t)$$

Comparing the coefficients we then have

$$A=1$$

$$6A+B=0$$

$$B=-6$$

$$4A+3B+C=0$$

$$C=14$$

$$-2E+3D+E=0$$

$$E=3D$$

$$-2D-3E+D=3$$

$$-D-3E=3$$

$$-D-3(3D)=3$$

$$D=-\frac{3}{10}$$

$$E=-\frac{9}{10}$$

$$y_p=t^2+(-6)t+(14)-\frac{3}{10} \sin t -\frac{9}{10} \cos t$$

The general solution is

$$y=y_c+y_p$$

$$y=c_1e^{\frac{-t}{2}}+c_2e^{-t}+t^2+(-6)t+(14)-\frac{3}{10} \sin t -\frac{9}{10} \cos t$$